# How to add ``` in Rmarkdown as it is (plain text)

Tags: r, r-markdown

In my rmarkdown text, if I type:

````
R code chunks surrounded by ```
````

After `Knit`, I get: R code chunks surrounded by “‘

How can I get ``` as plain text? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to "escape" special symbols like `` ` `` to have them show up as plain text. You can do that by putting a `\` before each one.

If you want to show backticks as inline code, there's a trick where you can use multiple backticks to start inline code, and as long as you have less backticks inside the inline code, they'll be displayed. So to show 3 backticks in a row, you start with 4 backticks, show 3 inside and end with 4.

Showing both types:

`````
 R code chunks are surrounded by \`\`\` or ```` ``` ````.
`````